# What is the meaning of the hash symbol in RabbitMQ syntax?

Tags: javascript, rabbitmq

I am a junior dev. The following code is Express code. Probably raising a socket.io event.

```
myEventServiceBus.subscribe('FooMessage', appName, ['abc.xyz.#'], onMessage)
```

I'm not exactly sure what `#` is doing.

Judging by the raised event `abc.xyz.leMessage` I'm guessing it tacks on `onMessage` to  `abc.xyz`?

I couldn't find anything on Google.

Comment: What kind of object is `myEventServiceBus` and where's the doc for that?   This question has to do with that library more so than Express or socket.io and you title and tags should represent that if you want to attract the right people to help you.

Comment: Ah, so the # is not JS/jQuery syntax. Gotcha

Comment: No.  That `#` is in a string and it's up to that specific API how it wants to interpret that string.

Comment: I think we use rabbitmq? Looks like `#` is the wildcard for multiple words.

https://alexandrugris.github.io/distributed/systems/2017/05/23/rabbitmq-patterns.html

Comment: `#` (hash) can substitute for zero or more words.

Answer (score 0):

Per this [generic rabbitMQ tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html), the `#` is a wildcard that stands for zero or more words in that location.